# How to convert this sql to sqlalchemy query? (YEAR, MONTH, COUNT in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

How to convert this sql to sqlalchemy codes?

```
SELECT YEAR(post.released_time), MONTH(post.released_time), COUNT(*) \
FROM post GROUP BY YEAR(post.released_time) AND MONTH(post.released_time)
```

Thanks for your helps ^_^ !

Comment: Read [SQL and Generic Functions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html#generic-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved~

```
db.session.query(sqlalchemy.func.year(Post.released_time), sqlalchemy.func.month(Post.released_time), sqlalchemy.func.count('*')).\
group_by(sqlalchemy.func.year(Post.released_time), sqlalchemy.func.month(Post.released_time)).all()
```